# Consuming Web Service in C#: Basic Authentification and dynamic endpoint url

Tags: c#, web-services, authentication

I am trying to call a soap web service from c#. With static URL and without authentification everything works well. I used wsdl and csc to generate an dll and also worked with web references. This point was the easy part.

For the dynamic URL I have seen http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/wsdldynamicurl.aspx but this is from 2005 and I don't known if this is obsolete. Is it correct to use the "normal" references?

My Web Service is using basic authentication but I cannot figure out how to give the user/password.

I have already seen http://benpowell.org/supporting-the-ws-i-basic-profile-password-digest-in-a-wcf-client-proxy/ but this looks really complicated and I hope that there will be a simpler way to implement the basic authentication.

Comment: Did you try this example given on the blog you mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

To implement basic authentication for your web request you will have to use NetworkCredential for your request.

```
NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential(user,password);

WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Url);
req.Credentials = creds;
```

If you are using Web Reference for accessing web service; while you create a object of your proxy class just assign credentials to it.

```
NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential(user,password);
proxy.Credentials = creds ;
//call your web methods here.
```

For dynamic URL the article, you have mentioned, should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please tell me where to find the WebRequest when I used web references? Sry, I am newbie.